# Combine Multiple Table on a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables.  The third table has foreign keys to the first two.  Please see the attached screenshot for reference.

I want to select rows from Medicines based on category_ID and in result of this query I also want to show Comp_Name and category_Name of the resulted rows.

[[image]]

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem" image data does not help others to reproduce the problem.. You need to use JOIN

Comment: This is really the very basics of relational data. You need to [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) those tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is query for you, you need to use INNER JOIN

```
select Comp_Name, Category_Name
from Medicines as m
inner join Categories as c on c.Category_ID = m.Category_ID
inner join Company as co on co.Comp_ID = m.Comp_ID
```

just add your WHERE clause...

```
where m.Category_ID = 'your category id'
```